# Getting RSE stats for Kynetx apps

Tags: krl

How do I get stats on ruleset evaluations (RSEs) for my Kynetx apps? It used to be a standard feature of AppBuilder, but I can't seem to find it anywhere in the new one or in the command line tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: It's alive!!!!!**

The command line gem now features the ability to query your app stats.
[image]

---

We have an API being deploy within the next few days to the next few weeks that will allow you to see your app stats from the command line gem. The command line gem will have it first and you will see a blog post go out on the Kynetx developer blog announcing it. Later, the API will be available publicly.

I will also update this answer when the API is deployed.

Comment: Awesome! I'll keep my eyes peeled.

Answer (score 2):

This has now been deployed in the newest version of the `krl command-line tool`

Run a `gem update krl` and then a `krl help stats_query` to learn how to use this new functionality.

Comment: I noticed that the other day when Mike Farmer made a commit on github. :) Thanks for the heads up!